# Two different directories for python files (Default + PyCharm)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I currently seem to have two different directories, one listed under Local\AppData\Programs and one under the PyCharm library (the IDE I started using). I was downloading a gmail APK (ezgmail), and I noticed the actions I took in the default IDLE and PyCharm shells had different results when trying to import the module.

Are these two instances of Python files different? If so, how should I combat installations in the future?

**Note:**

> I originally used pip to download ezgmail in the shell, but later clicked on the "download ezgmail" hyperlink suggestion by PyCharm.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm creates a virtual environment in which you install python packages. The IDLE uses the global python interpreter.

The two prgrams are looking for the libraries in different locations. PyCharm creates a virtual environment for every project you create (if you specify but its on by default)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks!